# SharedPreferences - Activity and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager

I am currently using the SharedPreferences to keep track of a list of items to perform work on in a BroadcastReceiver started through an AlarmManager. Everything works great except a particular scenario. When I trigger a new item to perform work on, let it do the work, then remove that item (all via SharedPreferences edits) it works beautifully while the application is running. When there is nothing in the list and I open the Task Manager and kill the application, all of the sudden the item appears back in the BroadcastReceiver (which is still running after the Application closes). What causes this behavior? Should I just kill all receivers on application exit? Does the Activity closing default back to a different SharedPreferences object when the Receiver is still running?

Code to add/remove items from the SharedPreferences object

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Config.PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final Editor editor = prefs.edit();
mUpdates = prefs.getStringSet(Config.PREFS_KEY_ACTIVE_TASKS, new HashSet<String>());

if (!mUpdates.contains(key)) {
    mUpdates.add(key);
} else {
    mUpdates.remove(key);
}
editor.putStringSet(Config.PREFS_KEY_ACTIVE_TASKS, mUpdates);
editor.apply();
```

The broadcast receiver code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Config.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(prefs.contains(Config.PREFS_KEY_ACTIVE_TASKS)) {
        Set<String> updates = prefs.getStringSet(Config.PREFS_KEY_ACTIVE_TASKS, null);
        if(updates != null) {
            Log.d("RECEIVER","Size="+updates.size());
            for(String key : updates) {
                EntityChangeManager.notifyListeners(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code to add/remove objects from the initial list, as expected I see

```
04-30 20:04:44.165: D/RECEIVER(27079): Size=1
04-30 20:04:44.165: D/RECEIVER(27079): Size=0
```

When I kill the application I see

```
04-30 20:04:43.244: D/ActivityThread(27079): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
04-30 20:04:43.244: D/ActivityThread(27079): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
04-30 20:04:43.254: D/ActivityThread(27079): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
04-30 20:04:43.264: D/RECEIVER(27079): Size=1
```

Points of interest:

- The receiver runs every second
- The receiver is started from an AlarmManager
- No special settings in the  declaration
- This is repeatable after uninstalling application, clearing out all prefs in the receiver (in case it was using a different one)

Comment: It appears this is directly related to using StringSet though I haven't identified the cause. Opted to manually build and parse a string instead of using stringset.

Answer (score 2):

Change `editor.apply();` to `editor.commit()`. The change may not be written to disk when you kill the app. From official document at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are completed as well as the commit itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had originally used commit and switched to apply in order to try to resolve the issue. Both worked the same way. Turns out the StringSet functionality doesn't understand changes to its content so even when you edit the data it appears to be the same to the sharedprefs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running into any nuances with using StringSet the solution is to write another attribute to the SharedPreferences object (like StringSet.size()) in tandem with the StringSet itself. The reason is the SharedPreferences library only compares the object to the stored object, and adding/removing data doesn't necessarily cause the object itself to change, so it appears as if there are no differences.

It's possible to check the size of the object and if it's 0 when you edit it, instead of editing it, just set the object to null before you save it to SharedPreferences. I opted for the second sharedpref setting and it has worked fine since.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is a relatively old question, I stumbled on the same problem. Bu for future references, this could be usefull.

**The problem**: old values where being retrieved from the BroadcastReceiver. This is caused by SharedPreferences who doesn't update the contents of a StringSet, because it is the same object.

The following things were changed to provide persistent storage by means of SharedPreferences (I don't know which things contributed to the solution):

- In the manifest I had `android:process=":remote"`, which had to be deleted.
- I used `Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` as mode in sharedpreferences (`context.getSharedPreferences(ref,Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)`)
- And finally (because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16318179/3590700) post), first committing a `null` value resolved my problem:

```
    editor.putStringSet(ref,null);
    editor.commit();
    editor.putStringSet(ref, valuesToBeStored);
```

I don't know if the first two changes were needed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12144285)

Comment: This answer relates to the problem when using StringSet. This answer gives a solution to the problem of ''When there is nothing in the list and I open the Task Manager and kill the application, all of the sudden the item appears back in the BroadcastReceiver''. The expected behavoiur of the program should be that the last saved value should be the retrieved value.

Comment: I'v editted my answer so the problem related to the question, is better answerd.